# Swagger-codegen : Separate template for request and response beans

Tags: java, swagger, swagger-codegen, jersey-1.0

I am using swagger codegen( java-jaxrs and 'swagger-codegen-maven-plugin') to genearte API, service and model classes(request and response) in my application.
So taking example of User module, I have a User.yaml file, where I define all the APIs.
Till now everything works fine, but what **I want is separate mustache template for request and response model class.**

e.g.

```
Class UserReq implements IRestRequest {

}
```

and

```
Class UserResponse implemnts **IRestResponse** {

}
```

**Note** : 
I did little research and found that there is a way to specify multiple templates for model classes (through property modelTemplateFiles) but that's not my requirement.

Thanks in advance.